# What are common places to put your delegates?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm having some trouble understanding the delegate/data source methodology. I understand that they exist in order for your class to get more information about itself, like its data or whether it should do something, I just don't always know where to put it.  For instance, if I'm using a UISplitViewController, how should I decide where to put its delegate. Are there hard and fast rules or do you have to do some work to figure out who should really be the delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a case of what things the delegate needs to do and which object is in the best position to do those things.  That being said, there are some standard uses that derive from that logic.  For example, if the object that needs a delegate is a view then the delegate is likely to be the matching view controller...or a separate object that the view controller provides.